# A pythonic way to get a list filtered by a Django table

Tags: django, python-2.7

I need to filter a list like this: `A = ['a','b','c','c','d','e']`
and I have a Django model T that contains a field unique which I know if the element is the same or not. Lets say `T(id, name_unique,...others_fields)`.
Lets say T has

```
id, name...
(1, 'b',...)
(2, 'c',...)
(3, 'f',...)
(4, 'g',...)
and alot rows more
```

I need a way (pythonic) to get a list A filtered by distinct and non repeated from name_unique, so the output should be

```
A' = ['a', 'd', 'e']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `set()` to create a unique list from a value_list, and do set type operations on it.
https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets

```
a = ['a','b','c','c','d','e']
a_set = Set(to_filter )

unique_names = MyModel.objects.values_list('name_unique', flat=True)
unique_names_set = Set(unique_names )

result = a_set.difference(unique_names_set)
```

The side effect of this is that it will render the values list, if the list is too large to turn into a set in one go, you can use an iterator.

edit: here is a solution with an iterator:

```
list=['a','b','c','d']
for m in Models.objects.all().iterator():
    list.remove(m.unique_name)
```

Comment: good one! can I filter values_list with a IN statement? MyModel.objects could be too innecesary large if I can filter via db query, right?

Comment: You can filter it for sure. you can also use `MyModel.objects.all().iterator()` to perform one query per object in a for loop or list comprehension. I added to the answer